# Как перезаписывать текстовый файл с помощью телеграмм бота?

Tags: python, telegram

Если коротко, то в папке bot создается текстовый файл куда выгружаются номера карт по порядку, цель бота просто перезаписывать все номера так, что бы рядом с ними был их баланс, который пользователь сам будет прописывать боту в сообщении. Для наглядности приведу пример: в текстовый файл загружаются номера карт по прядку, бот берет первый номер назовем его x, генерирует из него бар-код и отправляет в сообщении юзеру, юзер пикает этот бар-код у себя на кассе(это вообще не важно) получает допустим инфу, что на этой карте баланс n, юзер отправляет в сообщении этот баланс n, а бот в свою очередь перезаписывает текстовый файл таким образом: x(первый номер карты) + n(ее баланс) что бы выглядело это примерно так: 7789004400030635 - 567р, и так для всех остальных номеров, что бы все шло по циклу, надеюсь я понятно объяснил. Теперь проблема в том, что я ВООБЩЕ без понятия как это реализовать, я перепробовал все методы что знал(я еще новичок в питоне) и смог добиться лишь того, что бы бот генерировал бар-коды из списка карт и все( Ниже отправлю свой не до код и попрошу либо привести пример как это должно выглядеть, либо посоветовать полезную литературу, спасибо!

```
url = 'https://barcode.tec-it.com/barcode.ashx?data=' # URL

@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def start_bar_code_generation(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'начать': # запустить генерацию бар-кодов
        open_file = open('maps.txt', 'r') # текстовый файл с номерами
        for i in open_file:
            bar_code = url + i
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, bar_code)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Error! Команда не распознана!') # ошибка


bot.polling(none_stop = True, interval = 0)
```

Comment: получается карту не требуется указывать? баланс будет записываться к первой карте в списке, даже если это баланс не этой карты?

Comment: Баланс должен записываться поочередно для каждого номера карты в текстовом файле